# Code for Dummies: How to Make My Button Go?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Building out a page using DNN for my job, I don't like their shortcode button options, trying to code one myself. Main importance, I don't know how to code from scratch. I can jack other code together for a functional element, usually.

Code below ([alternatively, Codepen](https://codepen.io/mckrier/pen/GRMgaRK)) is as far as I've gotten. I want a blue button, white text, and a white hover action, got that far. My issue is in getting the button to GO. I substituted a link to Facebook instead of our site. Really, I just want an easy fill in the blank code we can drop into any block on the site to quickly change colors, link, and shown text. I feel like I'm close, but not quite there. Any suggestions on making my button go??

```css
        body {
          padding-left: 100px;
        }
    
        input#go {
          background-color: #4c9ed9;
          color: #ffffff;
          padding: 20px 40px;
          border: 1px solid #111;
        }
    
        input#go:hover {
          background-color: #ffffff;
          color: #4c9ed9;
          border: 1px solid #111;
        }
```

```html
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <title>MK Button 2</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <form>
      <input type="button" id="go" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.facebook.org';" value="Register">
      </form>
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine, it won't run on codepen since it's redirecting to facebook from that embedded editor inside the site instead of your own navigator

Comment: It wont connect to facebook for two reasons: the address is wrong (.com not .org) and as @YESSINE has pointed out facebook will in any case refuse a connection from codepen. Try another site's address.

Answer (score 3):

Your button should 'go' as is - but you might consider using an actual button element rather than an input element with type=button that lives in a form tag. This is easier to drop in.

```css
button#go {
      background-color: #4c9ed9;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 20px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #111;
    }

    button#go:hover {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #4c9ed9;
      border: 1px solid #111;
    }
```

```html
<button id="go" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.facebook.org';">Register</button>
```

Comment: There is a problem with the FB address (plus it wont connect through codepen).

Comment: Yes, they said it was just FPO. I assumed they would put their own website URL in there.